# Weired number when i used currentddate.setDate(currentddate.getDate() + 30) to add 30 days from today

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to add 30 days to the current date:-

```
var currentddate = new Date();
alert(currentddate);
var currentddate2 = new Date();
alert(currentddate2.setDate(currentddate2.getDate() + 30));
```

now the first alert will return the current date as follow `Wed Jun 12 2019 22:15:49 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)` but the second alert will return this weird number `1562966157303` ? so can anyone advice on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though `setDate` changes the date, its return value is:

> The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the
>   given date (the Date object is also changed in place)

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate

If you `alert(currentddate2)` again, you'll see that it was changed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If some API returns an unexpected result, first of all, look into the [docs!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate#Return_value)

> **Return value**
>
> The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date (the Date object is also changed in place).